# What is the practical use of the form g[x][y][z]?

Tags: functions, function-construction

Consider two functions, `f` and `g`. `f` is a curried function. It takes a single argument and returns another function. It seems that `f` and `g` are similar. However, their behaviours are quite different.

I want to know the practical use of `g[x][y][z]`, and under what circumstances I should use it.

In:

```
Clear[f, g]
f[x_] := y \[Function] z \[Function] x + y + z
f[x]
f[x][y]
f[x][y][z]

g[x_][y_][z_] := x + y + z
g[x]
g[x][y]
g[x][y][z]
```

Out:

> ```
> Function[y$, Function[z$, x + y$ + z$]]
> Function[z$, x + y + z$]
> x + y + z
>
> g[x]
> g[x][y]
> x + y + z
> ```

Derivative is like `g`. It isn't a typical example. I guess most of people use the operator ('), but not the general form `Derivative[n1,n2,...][f]`.

This question is inspired by the snippet of ClangCompiler.m.

```
ClangCompiler[method_][args___] := 
  CCompilerDriver`CCompilerDriverBase`BaseDriver[method][args]
```

After I went through CCompilierDriverBase.m, it seems that this form is like an association.

```
BaseDriver["OptionsExceptions"]["CreateLibrary"] := {"MprepOptions"}

BaseDriver["OptionsExceptions"]["CreateExecutable"] := {"LibraryType"}

BaseDriver["OptionsExceptions"]["CreateObjectFile"] := 
  {"ExtraObjectFiles", "Libraries", "LibraryType", "LinkerOptions", 
   "MprepOptions", "SystemLibraries", "SystemLinkerOptions"}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59567/discussion-on-question-by-unchartedworks-what-is-the-practical-use-of-the-form-g).

Answer (score 0):

This started out as another comment, but I turned it into an attempted answer.

If I interpret the question as "what can `g`-type functions do that `f`-type can't", I think it's similar to asking why one would want to use `SetDelayed` rather than `Set` together with `Function`.  You can a lot of things with `h=Function[...]`, but it can still be more elegant/useful to use `h[...]:=...`.  Then there are things like `foo[x_EvenQ]:=bar[x]` that leave `foo[3]` unevaluated.  It's also easier to add more definitions later with `SetDelayed`.